# Couldn't connect with QuickBooks Connector in mule esb

Tags: mule, quickbooks, mule-studio, connector, mule-component

I am facing a problem while connecting with the QuickBooks connector.

My keys are correct. Didn't find any solution how to solve this? Can any one help me?

**UPDATE**

Following is my flow

```
 <flow name="Authorize">
    <!-- INBOUND ENDPOINT -->
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <quickbooks:auth-user config-ref="Quickbooks_Online" accessTokenUrl="https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_access_token" authorizationUrl="https://appcenter.intuit.com/Connect/Begin" callbackUrl="http://localhost:8090" requestTokenId="#[groovy:message.getSessionProperty('requestTokenIdentifier')]" requestTokenUrl="https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_request_token" doc:name="Quickbooks Online"/>
</flow>
<flow name="GetAccessToken">

    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8090" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <quickbooks:get-access-token config-ref="Quickbooks_Online" doc:name="Quickbooks Online"/>
        <quickbooks:get-object config-ref="Quickbooks_Online" accessTokenId="#[groovy:message.getSessionProperty('accessTokenIdentifier')]" type="ACCOUNT" doc:name="Quickbooks Online"/>
        <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
        <logger message="O-JSON #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

</flow>
```

Now I got OAuthCredential error..

```
Message               : Failed to invoke getObject. Message payload is of type: OAuthCredentials
Code                  : MULE_ERROR-29999
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. ERROR CODE:3200, ERROR MESSAGE:message=ApplicationAuthenticationFailed; errorCode=003200; statusCode=401, ERROR DETAIL:null
 (com.intuit.ipp.exception.AuthenticationException)
  com.intuit.ipp.interceptors.HandleResponseInterceptor:83 (null)
2. org.mule.modules.quickbooks.api.exception.ExceptionInfo@a402a5[cause=message=ApplicationAuthenticationFailed; errorCode=003200; statusCode=401,errorCode=3200,message=ERROR CODE:3200, ERROR MESSAGE:message=ApplicationAuthenticationFailed; errorCode=003200; statusCode=401, ERROR DETAIL:null
] (org.mule.modules.quickbooks.api.exception.QuickBooksRuntimeException)
  org.mule.modules.quickbooks.online.api.DefaultQuickBooksOnlineClient:107 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/modules/quickbooks/api/exception/QuickBooksRuntimeException.html)
3. Failed to invoke getObject. Message payload is of type: OAuthCredentials (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.modules.quickbooks.online.processors.GetObjectMessageProcessor:153 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
```

Answer (score 2):

This error:

> The user token could not be retrieved from the Object Store using the key

tells you that you have not authenticated the connector correctly.

It's as if you haven't captured a valid token, either via `OpenID` or `OAuth`. Make sure to use one of these two methods to authenticate before calling the `greenropetestFlow1` flow.

Read the authentication guide for the QuickBooks connector here: http://mulesoft.github.io/quickbooks-connector/online/authentication.html

Comment: Exactly, you need to check the accessTokenId.

Comment: Thanks David.. I tried your suggestion. Now I got another error.. Please go through once. I update my Question

Comment: I am using Mule 3.6version

Comment: When my flow comes to <quickbooks:get-object....> at that time got error..After click on Authenticate button

Comment: Hi David..Can you please help me to solve this error

Comment: Take a look at this example: https://github.com/mulesoft/quickbooks-connector/tree/master/demo-qbo-oauth Try running it, when you can run it, you'll be ready to fix your own project.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, it seems the connector is out of the date and those authentication methods are just not working, no body has push changes since a couple of years.

I wrote a solution here:
https://yucelmoran.com/2018/02/12/authorization-process-for-quickbooks-online-using-mule-no-connector/

hope it helps, it's maybe just a temporally solution..